# Riverpod: How to use StateNotifier with Maps and update the UI?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to add/Update Maps to state of StateNotifier and then retrieve length of state as well as  update the UI when Map is added to or deleted from the state.

Right now, length is increasing and decreasing but UI is not updating.

Maps(key = productId, value = Cart which is model)

```
class Cart {
  final String dateId;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  Cart(
      {required this.dateId,
        required this.title,
        required this.quantity,
        required this.price});
}

class CartNotifier extends StateNotifier<Map<String, Cart>> {
  CartNotifier() : super({});

  int cartLength() {
    return state.length;
  }

  void add(String productId, double price, String title) {
    if (!state.containsKey(productId)) {
      Map<String, Cart> cartMap = {
        productId: Cart(
            dateId: 'dateId', title: title, quantity: 1, price: price),
      };
      state = {...state, ...cartMap};
    } else {
      state.update(
          productId,
              (existing) =>
              Cart(
                dateId: existing.dateId,
                title: existing.title,
                quantity: existing.quantity + 1,
                price: existing.price,
              ));
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Provider-

```
final cartProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CartNotifier, Map<String, Cart>>(
  (ref) => CartNotifier(),
);
```

This is where I am using the provider in build Method of ConsumerWidget-

```
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ref.read(cartProvider.notifier).add(
                    _idController.text,
                    double.parse(_priceController.text),
                    _titleController.text,
                  );
            },
            child: const Text('Submit'),
          ),
```

```
Text('${ref.read(cartProvider.notifier).cartLength()}'),
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked changing only one line of code-

```
Text('${ref.watch(cartProvider).length}'),
```

Instead of calling Method, call length on ref

Comment: its good. We can fetch data using final dataValue = ref.watch(counterProvider);
    String name = dataValue['name'].toString();
    String email = dataValue['email'].toString();
    String address = dataValue['address'].toString();

Answer (score 0):

We can set and fetch the data using Riverpod and hooks is as below answer. Have a look in this example.
Link:[Flutter Riverpod Statenotifier should rebuild on map changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739235/flutter-riverpod-statenotifier-should-rebuild-on-map-changes/73769413#73769413)